# No response message after calling an API

Tags: flutter

```
  Future<EventObject> addStudentToSubject(String studentCode, String subjectid) async {
try {
  final encoding = APIConstants.OCTET_STREAM_ENCODING;
  final response = await http.post('${APIConstants.API_BASE_LIVE_URL}/controller_educator/add_student_to_subject.php',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        'stud_code': studentCode,
        'subj_id': subjectid
      },
      encoding: Encoding.getByName(encoding)
  );
  print("YAWA" + response.body);
} catch (Exception) {
  return EventObject();
}
```

}

Is there something wrong with my code why i theres no response message??
Logcat just says "I/flutter ( 5013): YAWA"
Don't know what i'm missing.

Comment: Can you call the API via Postman ?

Comment: All of our API's are can't be tested in Postman, I don't know what our API developer have done to it.

Comment: Strange ! Do you have any other API which doesn’t work via Postman but works with Flutter program ?

Comment: Yep, same API "HttpProvider.post(context, "controller_educator/add_student_to_subject.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() " but works in android

Comment: Please give it a try, https://theyestech.com/controllerClass/controller_educator/register_as_educator_class.php, params = e_email_address, e_password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe your API does not work in Postman.  Can you indicate what status code did you get in Postman?

The problem in your code is your not checking the status code response of your API. The POST request you have called has probably had an empty body. Some POST request only returns the status code.

You should always check the status code of the API. If it returns 200 means your API has processed your request successfully.

```
final encoding = APIConstants.OCTET_STREAM_ENCODING;
final response = await http.post('${APIConstants.API_BASE_LIVE_URL}/controller_educator/add_student_to_subject.php',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        'stud_code': studentCode,
        'subj_id': subjectid
      },
      encoding: Encoding.getByName(encoding)
  );
print(${response.statusCode});
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
```

Comment: Mark my answer if you think it helps solve your problem.